# Is it possible to use AWS Lambda to request an oauth 2.0 token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, oauth

I am looking for ways to avoid creating an `ec2 instance` in order to have a valid callback URL to perform the oauth handshake.

I plan to use `Lambda` to connect to a remote `API`, but I need to be able to get the token first, which is valid only for 6 hours.

Is there any way I can make the handshake via `Lambda` functions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think `Lambda` along with `API Gateway` offer a good solution. API Gateway allows you to create a persistent, publicly accessible HTTP endpoint. You can define specific 'resources' that map HTTP methods to lambda function calls.

I'm not especially familiar with OAuth 2, but I'm imagining something like this: In API Gateway, define a resource '/callback' with a GET method that invokes your Lambda function.

Register the API Gateway endpoint as your application's callback URI, which would look something like this:

https://c1bql2cdxy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/callback

By doing so, the remote service will invoke your lambda function, which can then read the authorization token from the request and use it however needed, whether that involves 1) storing the token in a database for future use (and reuse) by other services, 2) directly invoking the services within the same Lambda function, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit and the answer, sounds promising. I will test everything and come back to mark it as correct.

Comment: Hi @rumdrums, the way oauth 2 works is that first you send a GET request to get a code and then use that code in a POST request with some other data as secret key, app id, etc. I am trying to understand API Gateway flow. I should create 2 different resources right? And then call them with my lambda function. Sorry if this does not make sense, I am trying to understand how it works. Thanks again

Comment: @JordanBelf I think you're definitely on the right track. Since the question was limited to the callback callback part of the process, I didn't give much thought to the initial part  -- where the user requests from your application an initial authorization link -- but I would think you would definitely want a separate Lambda service, accessible on a different URL, that the user can access to receive this link. From there, the user authenticates with the authorization service, at which point he is redirected to your callback URL. Does that make sense?