# Oauth2 to google people api on aws lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to use [google's people api](https://developers.google.com/people/) on aws lambda. As the api requires oauth2 I tried to fetch the oauth2 token locally and then transfer it to aws lambda:

I store the secrets with this function:

```
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client import client, tools

def get_credentials():
    credential_path = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'people-api-secret.json')
    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials
```

Then I transfer `people-api-secret.json` to aws lambda using the serverless framework. But when I try to load the secret on lambda, then `store.get()` returns `None`. The file is really there on AWS (`os.path.isfile(credential_path)` returns `True`).

Is it not possible to copy those secrets on another computer/IP address? If not: what would the "minimal way" of getting this to work without doing the "full fledged way" described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274708/is-it-possible-to-use-aws-lambda-to-request-an-oauth-2-0-token/41276096)

**Update** Found out that it's a simple "permission denied" error on lambda: `print(open(credential_path).read())` yields `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/people-api-secret.json'`. I guess those variables should be put into environment instead of being read from file?

Comment: Make sure you gave the right permission(chmod) to your json file before you deploy your lambda function. If you're downloading this file at runtime, try to save the credentials in the /tmp dir: '/tmp/people-api-secret.json', that's the only dir that you can write files in a Lambda Container.

Answer (score 4):

Upload your json with the secret key just as you're doing, then do this:

```
#import GoogleCredentials
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('people', 'v1', credentials=credentials,cache_discovery=False)
```

On your lambda configuration set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as environment variable key and your credentials json file name as value.

It works on all my lambdas that use google api.

Comment: Upload it where...?

Answer (score 1):

While giving the right permissions would probably have worked (according to Tom Melos comment and [this github issue](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth/issues/14)) I wanted to put the secret into an environment variable because this is described as best practice.

First I needed a way to get the token, so I ran this (that needs the file `client_secret.json` which you can download from the google api console following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python)):

```
from oauth2client import client, tools

class MyStorage(client.Storage):
    def locked_put(self, credentials):
    print("="*70)
    print("client_id: {}\nclient_secret: {}\nrefresh_token: {}".format(
        credentials.client_id, credentials.client_secret, credentials.refresh_token))
    print("="*70)

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly')
flow.user_agent = 'my-user-agent'
storage = MyStorage()
tools.run_flow(flow, storage)
```

The resulting three strings I put into the environment following [this guide](http://www.goingserverless.com/blog/keeping-secrets-out-of-git) and then was able to do this:

```
import os
from oauth2client import client
from apiclient import discovery

client_id = os.environ['GOOGLE_PEOPLE_CLIENT_ID']
client_secret = os.environ['GOOGLE_PEOPLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
refresh_token = os.environ['GOOGLE_PEOPLE_REFRESH_TOKEN']
credentials = client.GoogleCredentials(None, 
    client_id, 
    client_secret,
    refresh_token,
    None,
    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    'my-user-agent')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('people', 'v1', http=http,
    discoveryServiceUrl='https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest',
    cache_discovery=False)
```

For more details (personally I just learned the basics of Oauth2) I've [documented here](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/391#issuecomment-354414703) what happens in these requests and why we need the `refresh_token` here.